# How would I add a key/value pair to every single JSON file in a folder in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a folder containing ~10000 JSON files, and I'm looking to add a new identical key/value pair ("Symbol": "PPF") to each one.

Each JSON file is named using an increasing number: 0.json, 1.json, 2.json, ... 9999.json, 10000.json

My current best attempt was trying to remove the last line of every file (the final `}`), then append `,"Symbol": "PPF"`.

What would be the fastest way of adding that key/value pair to all JSON files?

Comment: How big are the files? Have you tried just opening them normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following looping over the files:

```
# Read a json file temp.json and convert to Python dict

import json

with open('temp.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data["key"] = "value"

# Write back to file

with open('temp.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```